# Drawing pie chart , getting data

Tags: javascript, java, charts, innerhtml

I am trying to learn java script. Used a code for getting some information from api and showing them in the web page perfectly. Now i want to make pie chart from those datas. Searched from google for learning but couldn't use them. Please help me learning.
Tried different combinations " ['Read', data.read]," for getting var data but i am rookie for java. I know trying wrone things but cant find the true.
Thanks

```
function situateCaseHandler() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            if (this.status === 300) {
                const json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                let data;
                for (let i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
                    if (json[i].country == "Read") {
                        data = json[i];
                    }
                }
                if (!data) {
                    return console.log("Error");
                }
                document.getElementById("read").innerHTML = data.read ;
                document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = data.write;
                document.getElementById("sleep").innerHTML = data.sleep ;


            }
        }
    };

    function makeRequests() {
        sendAllCasesRequest();
        senduserCasesRequest();
    };

// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Read', data.read],
  ['Write', data.write],
  ['Sleep', data.sleep]
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'User Day', 'width':550, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data2, options);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to call drawChart after your data has loaded as opposed to when the document has loaded.

Comment: Yes first getting data for html table, then i want to use same data numbers for my piechart. Can't used data in chart. There is no problem for making table but makin pie is empty ( ['Sleep', data.sleep] ) is wrong i think

Comment: google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); draws the chart when there is probably no data, hence why your graph is empty. Call drawChart after you've got the data, e.g. at the bottom of situateCaseHandler. Try putting a breakpoint or look at the network tab to determine if your data is in the correct format.

Comment: <div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>

      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Read</th>
        <th scope="col">Write</th>
        <th scope="col">Sleep</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Read"  class="info"><p id="Read></p></td>
        <td data-label="Write" class="danger"><p id="Write"></p></td>
        <td data-label="Sleep" class="success"><p id="Sleep"></p></td>
      
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="piechart"></div>

Comment: First i make the table, then calling the chart. if i give manuel number  ['Read', 20] it works. But i want to get the  document.getElementById("read").innerHTML = data.read  instead of 20 number

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems with your code, from what you've shared.

1. data is a local variable, so it will be undefined in your drawChart method.
2. drawChart gets called when the document has loaded and not when you've received your data, which is probably why your chart is empty.

As a suggestion, try and structure your code like below, so it's easy to understand.

```
let data = getDataFromApi();
renderDataInTable(data);
drawChart(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Shoejep, As i said before i am rookie and want to try learning javascript. I couldnt integrate your advice easily, and i am unsuccessfull.